# How to retain fragment of ViewPager inside a Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a viewPager inside a Fragment which is again inside an activity.I am generating dynamic fragments for a viewPager everytime(via AsyncTask) the fragment is created inside the activity.

Now When I rotate screen,configuration changes.I am retaining fragment using setRetainInstance(true).Hence it does not fire up AsyncTask again to generate dynamic fragments for ViewPager.

However after rotating,screen becomes completely white.The ViewPager fragment loses its data.App does not crash.Also I gave setRetainInstance(true) inside onCreate of the dynamic nested fragment.Nut App throws exception that you cannot retain Nested Fragment.

Then How can I retain the ViewPager fragment after rotating the screen?

Also setting setRetainInstance(true) in parentFragment also retains childFragments but in my case screen becomes white.ViewPager Fragment loses data.